# Is there a word for 'trapped in a good way'?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for the concept of being unable to leave a place, or end a condition, which you find pleasurable, rewarding, safe, etc...?

All the words I can think of for 'unable to leave' seem negative, e.g. trapped, imprisoned, stuck, ensnared.

Example: "We spent every cent on our dream house, and we are finally  in Palm Springs."

Comment: What do you think of **positively addicted**? That was the first thing to pop into my mind.

Comment: ***ensconced***?

Comment: **captivated**? **engrossed**? It'd be better if you provided us with a sample sentence to show how the word you're looking for is going to be used. As you can see, a lot of words can fit your description depending on the context.

Comment: Thanks! Ensconced and Engrossed are good; closer than anything I could think up. I suppose there might not be a perfect word for this, because having no option to leave/change is something kind of inherently bad.

Comment: Positively Addicted is good, too, but I'm really hunting for a single word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two very similar words that I can think of are the following:

[**engrossed**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/engrossed):

> so interested or involved in something that you think about nothing else
>
> Example:
>
> *He was so **engrossed** in his book that he didn’t hear her come in.*

[**absorbed**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/absorbed):

> very interested in something and not paying attention to anything else
>
> Example:
>
> *Simon was so **absorbed** in his book that he didn't even notice me come in.*

Comment: I think 'engrossed' takes the grand prize. Thanks!